# TinyMce templates

Tags: javascript, templates, tinymce

Using the template plugin for Tinymce. I can't make the templates load. When the plugin is called the title of the template it appears but nothing else is loaded in and when I clicked OK the popup disappears but no template is loaded in. The file path for the template is correct so I don't see why it isn't loading in.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#messaging",
            width: "700px",
            height: "300px",
            resize: false,
            toolbar: "template | undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent",

            plugins: "template",            
            templates: [
                {title: 'Signature', description: 'Insert and edit your signature', url: 'tinymce/templates/signature.html'}            
            ]

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post">
        <textarea id="messaging"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basic template for example:

```
<div class="mceTmpl">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Any help here would be gratefully received.

Edit: works fine in Firefox so I'm assuming this is down to Chrome, ps this is all being ran locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this setup:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/Scripts/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js")     // May required        
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js")           
        <script>
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea#messaging',
                height: 375,
                menubar: true,
                resize: true,
                toolbar_items_size: 'small',
                toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | fontselect fontsizeselect lineheight | link print preview fullpage ",
                plugins: [
                    "advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime nonbreaking",
                    "save table contextmenu directionality paste textcolor lineheight"
                ]
            });
        </script>
```

And make it sure that your render it in correct path.

Comment: Sorry, don't get it - where is the template?